# How does this work in a table in python naming each column and row in a different variable and is there alternatives?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a table that looks like this

```
testingTable = [["www.facebook.com", "157.240.195.35"],
            ["www.twitch.tv", "151.101.14.167"],
            ["www.youtube.com", "172.217.19.174"],
            ["www.apple.com", "23.218.43.196"],
            ["www.discord.com", "162.159.135.232"],
            ["www.hltv.org", "104.18.2.89"]]
lookFor = input('Enter a HostName or an IP address to look for: ')

for i in testingTable:
    hostName, IP=i
```

what does this line   (hostName, IP=i) do exactly without it does not run but with it it knows that the first element in every tuple is hostName and the second is IP can someone explain to me how does this work  (hostName, IP=i) inside the loop

Comment: Why would you call your loop variable `i`? Call it `row` or something nicer.

Answer (score 1):

In python you have tuple unpacking, which allows you to do this:

```py
my_iterable = [1,2,3]
a, b, c = my_iterable
print(a) 
# 1
print(b)
# 2
print(c)
# 3
```

In short, you are assigning the first element of `my_iterable` to the variable `a` and so forth.

In your example, you loop over your list `testingTable`, so the first element, `i` (you probably can find a better name) has the value `["www.facebook.com", "157.240.195.35"]`. You then unpack it into `hostname="www.facebook.com"` and `IP="157.240.195.35"`

Answer (score 1):

```
hostName, IP=i
```

is equal to

```
hostName=i[0]
IP=i[1]
```

Comment: so it takes both names I provided (hostName and IP) and assign them to the loop iteration variable "i" as [0] and [1] depends on the order I did yes ?

Comment: your for-loop `for i in testingTable:` assigns a tuple to `i` in each iteration. `i` then gets unpacked into the variables `hostName` and `IP` by `hostName, IP=i`